# param is missing or the value is empty: story rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
param is missing or the value is empty: story
```

I am getting this weird error where I the required param is missing:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @invite = Invite.new
  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
 end

 def invite_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:title, :story, :body, :id, :user_id)
 end
```

end

In the error screen, the parameters clearly states that `story => "3"`:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WDwu3UR/ZtAMKFVwJP4bb83BvdG+RBndP1wKBYT4t7V4BX2N/j/0Tl7VlJnHjObS7ahh2Qjw5oSwuKGyrUgWQw==", "invite"=>{"story"=>"3", "email"=>"1@live.com"}, "commit"=>"Send"}


class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :story
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end

create_table "invites", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.integer  "story_id"
  t.integer  "sender_id"
  t.integer  "recipient_id"
  t.string   "token"
  t.boolean  "accept"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.index ["story_id"], name: "index_invites_on_story_id", using: :btree
end
```

Do I have to manually link the `@invite.new` with the `require(:story)`, if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `require` attribute incorrectly.

It was suppose to be `params.require(:invite ).permit(:title, :story, :body, :id, :user_id)`.

The class `invite` requires `invite`, as oppose to an external story.